# MapReduce or Spark for Batch processing on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, batch-processing, apache-spark

I know that MapReduce is a great framework for batch processing on Hadoop. But, Spark also can be used as batch framework on Hadoop that provides scalability, fault tolerance and high performance compared MapReduce. Cloudera, Hortonworks and MapR started supporting Spark on Hadoop with YARN as well.

But, a lot of companies are still using MapReduce Framework on Hadoop for batch processing instead of Spark.

So, I am trying to understand what are the current challenges of Spark to be used as batch processing framework on Hadoop?

Any thoughts?

Comment: hadoop -> the old way, Spark -> the new way.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM in your cluster? Spark loves RAM. M/R goes to disk for everything, supports larger datasets.

Comment: You said "But, a lot of companies are still using MapReduce Framework on Hadoop for batch processing instead of Spark." Do you have any data to support this claim ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Based on the data, I asked this question.  But, data cannot be shared.  I am very much convinced that Spark is better and it will become mainstream in future.  So, companies not adapting Spark at this point of time is because of stability or any other reasons?

Answer (score 6):

Spark is an order of magnitude faster than mapreduce for iterative algorithms, since it gets a significant speedup from keeping intermediate data cached in the local JVM.

With Spark 1.1 which primarily includes a new shuffle implementation ([sort-based shuffle](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2045) instead of hash-based shuffle), a [new network module](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2468) (based on netty instead of using block manager for sending shuffle data), a new [external shuffle service](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3796) made Spark perform the fastest PetaByte sort (on 190 nodes with 46TB RAM) and TeraByte sort breaking Hadoop's old record.

Spark can easily handle the dataset which are order of magnitude larger than the cluster's aggregate memory. So, my thought is that Spark is heading in the right direction and will eventually get even better.

For reference this [blog post](http://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html) explains how databricks performed the petabyte sort.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming when you say Hadoop you mean HDFS.

There are number of benefits of using Spark over Hadoop MR.

1. **Performance:** Spark is at least as fast as Hadoop MR. For iterative algorithms (that need to perform number of iterations of the same dataset) is can be a few orders of magnitude faster. Map-reduce writes the output of each stage to HDFS.

   1.1. Spark can cache (depending on the available memory) this intermediate results and therefore reduce latency due to disk IO.

   1.2. Spark operations are lazy. This means Spark can perform certain optimizing before it starts processing the data because it can reorder operations because they have executed yet.

   1.3. Spark keeps a lineage of operations and recreates the partial failed state based on this lineage in case of failure.
2. **Unified Ecosystem:** Spark provides a unified programming model for various types of analysis - batch (spark-core), interactive (REPL), streaming (spark-streaming), machine learning (mllib), graph processing (graphx), SQL queries (SparkSQL)
3. **Richer and Simpler API:** Spark's API is richer and simpler. Richer because it supports many more operations (e.g., groupBy, filter ...). Simpler because of the expressiveness of these functional constructs. Spark's API supports Java, Scala and Python (for most APIs). There is experimental support for R.
4. **Multiple Datastore Support:** Spark supports many data stores out of the box. You can use Spark to analyze data in a normal or distributed file system, HDFS, Amazon S3, Apache Cassandra, Apache Hive and ElasticSearch to name a few. I'm sure support for many other popular data stores is comings soon. This essentially if you want to adopt Spark you don't have to move your data around.

For example, here is what code for word count looks in Spark (Scala).

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("some file on HDFS")
val wordCounts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey((a, b) => a + b)
```

I'm sure you have to write a few more lines if you are using standard Hadoop MR.

Here are some common misconceptions about Spark.

1. *Spark is just a in-memory cluster computing framework*. However, this is not true. Spark excels when your data can fit in memory because memory access latency is lower. But you can make it work even when your dataset doesn't completely fit in memory.
2. *You need to learn Scala to use Spark*. Spark is written in Scala and runs on the JVM. But the Spark provides support for *most* of the common APIs in Java and Python as well. So you can easily get started with Spark without knowing Scala.
3. *Spark does not scale*. Spark is for small datasets (GBs) only and doesn't scale to large number of machines or TBs of data. This is also not true. It has been used successfully to sort [PetaBytes of data](http://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html)

Finally, if you do not have a legacy codebase in Hadoop MR it makes perfect sense to adopt Spark, the simple reason being all major Hadoop vendors are moving towards Spark for good reason.

Comment: Well, my question is why MR is preferred over spark for batch processing by many companies today.  All new projects (batch) are implemented in MR only.  Why not Spark? Is it because of spark is not as stable as MR? Or any other challenges?

Comment: I'm afraid that's a hard question to answer either way. Where is the data that shows that companies are selecting MR over Spark?  IMO, many have MR because it existed long before Spark did. Spark is still not main stream yet but I don't see any other reason why I won't become mainstream. In my answer above I've tried to give as key "technical" reasons why I think Spark is better than MR and why it is likely to replace MR in the future.

Comment: I agree with Soumya that time is probably most important factor when it comes to the adoption of Apache Spark.
When 64 bit architectures were introduced, people also didn't immediately switch their operating system because migrations are always complicated and risky. The same applies to companies which started with MR and now slowly start to look into other alternatives.
I don't know if there are many companies today which decide to use MR over other next generation runtimes like Spark.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark runs in memory, making it much faster than mapreduce. 
Spark started as a research project at Berkeley.

Mapreduce use disk extensively (for external sort, shuffle,..).

As the input size for a hadoop job is in order of terabytes. Spark memory requirements will be more than traditional hadoop.

So basically, for smaller jobs and with huge memory in ur cluster, sparks wins. And this is not practically the case for most clusters.

Refer to spark.apache.org for more details on spark

Comment: "Apache Spark runs in memory" - I don't think this is completely correct. Spark performs the best if your dataset fits in memory. But it can handle operations even when your dataset doesn't fit in memory. Spark in most cases is as fast as Hadoop map-reduce.